# Netbeans 6.7 freezes on launch after crash. Any hints?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7

My wonderful corporate Dell crashed when "hibernating", and now NetBeans freezes when launching. (It displays the full interface, and starts "Scanning Projects", but doesn't get past there and I can't click on anything.)

I imagine there's some cache somewhere to clear out or something. Anyone know where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda had that type of problem before. What I end up doing to resolve that problem is to remove all the project entries that were loaded but not closed when I closed the problem. They are in:

.netbeans/6.X/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties

In the entries:

openProjectsDisplayNames.0=PROJECTNAME
openProjectsURLs.0=file:/PATH/TO/PROJECT

Comment: emptying that file didn't help, but clearing out utilities/RecentFilesHistory.properties under the same path did.

Comment: Oh, right. I mis-remembered the path now. That's the way to go.